# EXC_BAD_ACCESS code = 2 on SKView using swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, exc-bad-access

Im trying to port a game I made using objective C to swift. Ive got a scene initialized but im getting a bad access error whenever I assign the view object of my view controller to an SKView constant.

the line causing the error is below:

```
let skView = self.view as SKView
```

here is some more code for context:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        // Configure the view.

        /* Pick a size for the scene */
        let scene = GameplayScene(size: self.view.bounds.size, colored: false)
        // Configure the view.
        println("view: \(self.view.description)")
        let skView: SKView = self.view as SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
```

when I print the view object I get information in the console (memory address etc). Ive tried placing this code in different methods such as viewDidLoad etc but its the same result each time. I enabled zombies in my scheme but that didnt find anything (from what I could tell, nothing really happened). My game is a landscape game if that makes a difference. Anyone know what might be causing this pesky error? Ive set multiple breakpoints, the scene initializes fine, the println gets called, and then right when the the view gets set is when it crashes

Answer (score 0):

well figured it out about 2 minutes after posting this question. After logging the view in my test project I noticed that it was already of type SKView even before the self.view as SKView line. So I checked the view in the viewController and sure enough its class is SKView.

after changing the view in my actual games view controller from UIView to SKView it worked fine. that was an easy fix but a tough one to debug.

Comment: I almost always find the answer soon after posting. But only if I actually post. Somehow it's a necessary condition.

Comment: yeah that seems to be how most of my questions go